# python unexpected output for list operation

Tags: python, list

i wanted to remove all elements form list individually using list.remove(element)
so, i made code:

```
a=[12,34,23]
for i in a:
    a.remove(i)
print(a)
```

But I got:

```
[34]
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: Because you shouldn't modify the list while iterating through it. (add/remove elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening, because the first time `i` is pointing towards the first element, it removes 12, now `i` increases and points to the second element, and the second element now is 23 and not 34, so it removes 23.

To fix this error, you can do something like:

```
a = [12, 34, 23]
for i in a:
   a.remove(0)
print(a)
```

Comment: "i becomes 2" is a bit oversimplified, though what you're trying to say is fundamentally correct…

Comment: Yes, Thank You, actually I was just trying to explain it in simple words, it should be i refers to the 2nd element, right?

Comment: Yes, *2nd element*, not literally `2`.

Comment: i understood. but make it 2nd element